# where do i refer this type, numpy.array(x>0, dtype=np.int), function?

Tags: arrays, numpy

When I use `numpy.array(x > 0, dtype=np.int)`, I guess the function returns `1` if `x > 0` is satisfied or otherwise returns `0`. Where can I refer to documentation for this function? I have tried to find this function in the numpy documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), but I couldn't find it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def step_function(x):
    return np.array(x > 0, dtype=np.int)

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.001)
y = step_function(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's the correct function documentation. The `x>0` produces boolean True/False.  The dtype tells `array` to convert that to the equivalent integers, 1/0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!